# Python Client/Server send big size files

Tags: python, file, sockets, send, directory

I am not sure if this topic have been answered or not, if was I am sorry:

I have a simple python script the sends all files in one folder:

Client:

```
import os,sys, socket, time
def Send(sok,data,end="292929"):
    sok.sendall(data + end);
def SendFolder(sok,folder):
    if(os.path.isdir(folder)):
        files = os.listdir(folder);
        os.chdir(folder);
        for file_ in files:
            Send(sok,file_);#Send the file name to the server
            f = open(file_, "rb");
            while(True):
                d = f.read();#read file
                if(d == ""):
                    break;
                Send(sok, d, "");#Send file data
            f.close();
            time.sleep(0.8);#Problem here!!!!!!!!!!!
            Send(sok,"");#Send termination to the server
            time.sleep(1);#Wait the server to write the file
        os.chdir("..");
        Send(sok,"endfile");#let the server know that we finish sending files
    else:
        Send("endfile")#If not folder send termination
try:
    sok1 = socket.socket();
    sok1.connect(("192.168.1.121",4444))#local ip
    time.sleep(1);
    while(True):
        Send(sok1,"Enter folder name to download: ");
        r = sok1.recv(1024);
        SendFolder(sok1,r);
        time.sleep(0.5);
except BaseException, e:
    print "Error: " + str(e);
    os._exit(1);
```

Server:

```
import sys,os,socket,time
# receive data
def Receive(sock, end="292929"):
    data = "";
    while(True):
        if(data.endswith(end)):
            break;
        else:
            data = sock.recv(1024);
    return data[:-len(end)];#return data less termination
def FolderReceive(sok):
    while(True):
        r = Receive(sok);# recv filename or folder termination("endfile")
        if(r == "endfolder"):
            print "Folder receive complete.";
            break;
        else:
            filename = r;#file name
            filedata = Receive(sok);# receive file data
            f = open(filename,"wb");
            f.write(filedata);
            f.close();#finish to write the file
            print "Received: " + filename;
try:
    sok1 = socket.socket();
    sok1.bind(("0.0.0.0",4444));
    sok1.listen(5);
    cl , addr = sok1.accept();#accepts connection
    while(True):
        r = Receive(cl);
        sys.stdout.write("\n" + r);
        next = raw_input();
        cl.sendall(next);#send folder name to the client
        FolderReceive(cl);
except BaseException, e:
    print "Error: " + str(e);
    os._exit(1);
```

I know this not best server ever...but is what I know. This just work for a folder with small files because if I send big files(like 5mb...) it crashes because the time the client waits for the server is not enough.

So my question is how can I send the files to the server without client need to wait??or know exactly how many time the client needs to wait for the server to receive the file?? Some code that does the same but handling any file size, any help?

Comment: Yes I know python don't need ";" and "()" on IFs but I like to do this way!!!!

Comment: Well, it makes your code harder to read for experienced Python developers—the very people you want to help you here.

Comment: Meanwhile, `if(data.endswith(end)):` isn't going to work, because the end marker could come _anywhere_ in a packet, not just at the end of a packet. (It will also be a big problem if that "292929" string can appear in the files you want to send—e.g., if you try to send a directory including this script…)

Comment: Also, putting in `sleep` calls to wait for something to happen elsewhere is never a good idea. No matter what time you pick, it's not going to be enough all the time (plus, of course, most of the time, it will be way too long, slowing down your code for no reason).

Comment: Ok, I could put something harder but I believe that's not why is not working...

Comment: What do you mean by "put something harder"?

Comment: I am sorry about that(I am not English). I mean "sdçkfdnlsknfsldd-f"

Comment: I know the code have many problems, and I am sorry but I just wanted a way to send files in the folder and I am not the best in python.

Comment: That has the exact same two problems. There's still absolutely no reason to expect that to come at the end of a packet in `read`. And meanwhile, it will still prevent you from sending the script source, or the text of this page. If you want to use a string delimiter, you need escaping (or other techniques).

Comment: Can you write a little of code, just to see how would you do to receive files?

Comment: There's sample code in the Python docs, and in the blog post I linked to, and in 100 other questions on SO, some of which are already linked from here as Related questions. But honestly, I wouldn't design my own protocol from scratch and write the code from scratch. This is a solved problem. You can use FTP, SCP, rsync, TFTP, HTTP, JSON-RPC, etc., using a tool or python library that's already been designed, built, and debugged.

Comment: yeah, that is actually a good idea have never though about use ftp modules to send the file. But that doesn't mean that I have to connect to a server again?? Because this just a function of a code that doesn't only download folders so I wanted to keep communicating through tcp and just use ftp(example) to send the files and next get back the question "Enter Folder name: "(tcp), is that possible? Different ports, different threads would that work??

Comment: I'm not really sure what your program is trying to do, so it's hard to say whether FTP or the like would be useful. But yes, you can easily open two sockets on two different ports with a thread for each socket and they'll work concurrently, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). If you want to send a series of separate messages (like your separate files), you need to define a protocol, and then write a protocol handler. There is no way around that; just guessing at the timing or trying to take advantage of packet boundaries cannot possibly work.

The blog post linked above shows one way to do it. But you can do it with string delimiters if you want. But you have to deal with two problems:

- The delimiter can appear anywhere in a `read` packet, not just at the end.
- The delimiter can be split on packet boundaries—you may get `"2929"` at the end of one read, and the other `"29"` at the start of the next.

The usually way you do that is to accumulate a buffer, and search for the delimiter anywhere in the buffer. Something like this:

```
def message(sock, delimiter):
    buf = ''
    while True:
        data = sock.read(4096)
        if not data:
            # If the socket closes with no delimiter, this will
            # treat the last "partial file" as a complete file.
            # If that's not what you want, just return, or raise.
            yield buf
            return
        buf += data
        messages = buf.split(delimiter)
        for message in messages[:-1]:
            yield message
        buf = message[-1]
```

---

Meanwhile, you have another problem with your delimiter: There's nothing stopping it from appearing in the files you're trying to transmit. For example, what if you tried to send your script, or this web page?

That's one of the reasons that other protocols are often better than delimiters, but this isn't hard to deal with: just escape any delimiters found in the files. Since you're sending the whole file at once, you can just use `replace` on right before the `sendall`, and the reverse `replace` right before the `split`.

Comment: Well thanks, I think I'm gonna look better in all code to see what's the best way to make it work! And I know that the code above is just a big mess!...